# Array of Arrays to table

Tags: java, arrays, jtable

Faced problem of printing Array of Arrays to table. My program saves table data to separate text files (separate file for each day). Now I want to Read it all and sum each fields.
My saved text files looks like:

```
0   Name    auto    note    note.tot    insurance   ins.tot offer
1   john    51  6   2   21  44  12  
2   peter   32  5   1   36  65  20  
3   smith   12  2   1   45  53  9   
4   mike    5   0   0   17  55  11
```

I have manged a way to read it and save number values to arrays[][]. But now I need to print that arrays to table.

Here is my Read from files code:

```java
OK4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        File f = new File(fileName);
        if (f.exists()) {
            try {
                tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[] {"#", "Name", "auto", "note", "note.tot", "insurance", "ins.tot", "offer"},0);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
                String line = br.readLine();
                String[] colHeaders = line.split("\\s+");
                tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(colHeaders);

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] data = line.split("\\s+");
                    tableModel.addRow(data);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This date was not saved");
        };
        table.setModel(tableModel);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(22);
    }
});
```

And here is a code I am getting problems with:

```
OK5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int[][] array = null;
        int counter = 0;
        mon = (String) month.getValue();
        for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
            counter = 0;
            fileName= mon + i + ".txt";
            File f = new File(fileName);
            if (f.exists()) {
                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
                    String line = br.readLine();
                    String[] colHeaders = line.split("\\s+");
                    tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[] {"#", "name", "auto", "note", "note.tot", "insurance", "ins.tot", "offer"}, 0);
                    tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(colHeaders);

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        counter = counter + 1;
                        String[] info = line.split("\\s+");
                        for(int j = 2; j < 8; j++) {
                            int num = Integer.parseInt(info[j]);
                            array[j][counter]=array[j][counter] + num;
                        }
                    };
                } catch (Exception ex) {}
            };
        };

        // and here is trying to display it. but it wont work
        tableModel.addRow(array[1][]);
    }
});
```

error code is:
int cannot be converted to vector

But should I convert it to vector? may be there is another way to display it in table?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the errorcode is completely senseless, since the actual error is simply the access of the matrix: `tableModel.addRow(array[1][]);` should actually result in a syntax-error for the second brackets (`[]`). To fix the syntax error replace the line with `tableModel.addRow(array[1]);`. And a general note: please format your code, it is completely unreadable.

Comment: there's some code missing, but i guess `tableModel` is of type `AbstractTableModel`, not `DefaultTableModel`

Comment: Well all I want to do is somehow to display my array[][] to table. Is it necessary convert all my  '  int array  '  to vector or target table field by field or there is another way to display it?

Comment: `DefaultTableModel` does accept `Object[]` as argument for `addRow`. You'll have to use `Integer[][]` instead of `int[][]` for `array`

Comment: integer [][] removes error code, but it seems I will need write it line by line, cause it wont post null arrays.